# Opening forms from another project

Tags: c#

So I want to open Form from another project in C# so far I tried to go via Process.Start didn't help, I tried to do it easy way form new form form.show got ton of errors. Is there any way to open Form from another Project because all stuff that I tried didn't work at all. Help.

Comment: If it's a publicly defined form you should be able to create an instance and show it. What errors are you getting?

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Novi_Upis_Mihanoviceva.Noviupis threw an exception. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When I do reference to this form and go the easy way form new form and when I go Process.Start get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is suppose to work:

```
ProjectB.Form1 frm = new ProjectB.Form1();
frm.Show();
```

ProjectB here is the name of the namespace of your other project.

Now if Visual Studio is complaining that it cannot find the namespace of the other project, you need to add a reference on it.

To add a reference:

1. Right click on References of your first project
2. On Projects section, look for the other project that you want to reference on it, and check it.

This is the sample screenshot to guide you:

[image]

Comment: Try it, already, got this error  `System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Novi_Upis_Mihanoviceva.Noviupis threw an exception.` `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Most likely, the error is in the form that you are calling. You need to check the code in your form. There must be something that is null on your variables or objects but you still access its properties. This is just a guide since I am limited on the details of your program.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway :)